# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "Sinn" und "Bedeutung"?

Tags: difference

Ein Wort zum Beispiel kann eine oder mehrere "Bedeutungen" haben, aber wohl an sich keinen "Sinn".

Comment: Die Frage ist von ähnlicher Qualität wie "was ist der Unterschied zwischen einem Schnapsglas und einer Flasche" - Es sind zwei vollkommen unterschiedliche Begriffe, die nur am Rand miteinander zu tun haben.

Comment: Ich verstehe wie man zu so einer Frage kommen kann. Das Wort "Bedeutung" wird von Zeit zu Zeit anstelle von Sinn in der Alltagssprache gebraucht, aber es ist wirklich keine Frage dessen Antwort sich nicht mit jedem Deutsch Wörterbuch beantworten ließe.

Comment: Ich verstehe auch, wie man auf die Frage kommen kann, das haben auch schon andere geschafft, z.B. der Philosoph Gottlob Frege - und der hat einen 25-seitigen Aufsatz darüber geschrieben. Das wäre für hier ein bißchen lang... Gottlob Frege: Über Sinn und Bedeutung. In: Zeitschrift für Philosophie und philosophische Kritik. Band 100, 1892

Comment: @tofro Naja, ob ein sprachphilosophischer Text in der Lage ist irgendetwas über Sinn auszusagen darf dann doch bezweifelt werden ;-)

Comment: @ikadfoanhfda Genau dafür ist er doch schließlich da?